# A question on limit of weak-* convergence of probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space. Assume $X$ is compact. It is well-known that the space $\mathcal{P}(X)$ of probability measures on $X$ is compact in weak-* topology. Let's consider a sequence of probability measure $\{\frac{1_{Y_i}}{C}\mu\}_i$, where $Y_i \subset X$ is a measurable set with $|Y_i|=C$ . It has a subsequence converging to a probability measure $\mu_\infty$. Is $\mu_\infty$ also of the form $\frac{1_{Z}}{|Z|}\mu$ for some measurable set $Z\subset X$?

**Edit**
As some people pointed out, the assumption was week. I made a few changes.

Comment: A minor modification to the example in Francois Ziegler's answer will still work for the edited version of the question.

Comment: >Ricardo I don't see how one can modify his example.

Comment: @Sebastiani: Sorry, I was mistaken.

Comment: Still not research level. This belongs on math.stackexchange.

Comment: I believe that the question is vague at best, as the role of $\mu$ is unclear, (in general, the "appearance" of the limit measure can be written that way for $Z=supp(\mu)$). 

I believe that the real question here is whether $\mu_\infty$ is a.c. wrt $\mu$. 
In this case, the answer is no, as can be seen i.e. by taking $\mu$ to be supported on countably many points in the one-torus, and proper choice of weights and $Y_i$'s will force the Haar measure as a limit point, just by enlarging the period. Another example will be Sarnak's theorem about equidistribution of closed horocycles.

Comment: But when one uses the horocycles, one needs to thicken them a bit in tubular neighbourhoods to make an honest "positive measure" set.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $X=[0,1]$ with Lebesgue $\mu$. Let $Y_i=[0, 1/2]\cup \bigcup_{k=0}^{i-1} [1/2+(2k)/(4i),1/2+(2k+1)/(4i)]$.  The limiting measure is supported on the entire $[0,1]$, but it is not uniform: its density equals $4/3$ on the left half of the interval and $2/3$ on the right.

Comment: I am confused with your answer. It seems to me that your $Y_i$ is not in $[0,1]$. Also, I want $|Y_i|=C$ for a fixed constant $C$.

Comment: I was typing that on an ipad, sorry for sloppiness. It is clear that you need to restrict my $Y_i$'s to $[0,1]$. Let me make a correction now. UPD. Done. The total length of those intervals is always equal to $C=3/4$.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't $(X,\mu)=(\mathbf R,\text{Lebesgue measure})$ and $Y_i=[-\frac1i,\frac1i]$  already provide a counterexample, where $\mu_\infty$ is Dirac measure at the origin?

Comment: Thank you for the counter example. The condition was too weak. I now made a few changes in my question.

Comment: Then take $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue, and $Y_i = [\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{i}, \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{i}]$.  Of course you can do something like this to get a singular measure as the limit, as well.

Comment: > Gerald The constant $C$ is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Really a comment but have too few brownie points.  As usual on questions of this nature om MO, there is some confusion about the setting.  Usually, the space of probability measures is not compact in any sensible topology.  One case where it IS is that of radon measures on a compact space $K$, when provided with the weak $\ast$ topology as the dual of $C(K)$.  Even in this case,the claim is wrong as noted in the existing answer which can be adspted to the measure space $[0,1]$ (should it not be the interval $[-\frac 1 i, \frac 1 i]$ though?).

edit due to comment below.  but that is EXACTLY what i wrote (even with capitals).  one more time:  if $K$ is compact, then so is the space of probabiliy measures.  this is false, for example, on the real line where the natural weak topology is that induced by the space of bounded, continuous functions.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I still belies that $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is weak-* compact for a compact space $X$. I made a few changes in my post.

Comment: @coblenz Thanks for setting me straight on $[-\frac1i,\frac1i]$. I have fixed my answer accordingly.